# bash, echo несколько строк объединить в одну

Tags: bash

Хочу обе переменные внести в файл, естественно в файл уходит только вторая переменная. А если не разделять, то естественно ругается *cut*. Как правильно это сделать?

```
URL=https://git.git.ru/scm/hg/common/cpp
SHORT=fc88eab89100

echo $URL | cut -d"/" -f4-; echo $SHORT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eще, пожалуй,

```
# 3
echo $(cut -d/ -f4- <<<$URL)$SHORT
```

и

```
# 4
echo ${URL#*/*/*/}$SHORT
```

<sub>P.S. Every time you write an extra pipe G*d kills a kitten.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

```
 # 1
 echo $(echo $URL | cut -d"/" -f4-)${SHORT}


 # 2
 ONE_PATH=$(echo $URL | cut -d"/" -f4-)
 echo "${ONE_PATH}${SHORT}" >> output.txt
```

> да, конечно, полностью согласен c [bipll](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/292031/bipll), - "котята должны жить". Нет необходимости использовать конвейер (pipe) (выполнять команды в "под-оболочке"). Использование `<<<` (here strings) более изящно и уместно в данном случае.

Comment: Сложно будет такое поддерживать, если говорить о рабочих скриптах которые передаются внутри коллектива.

Comment: Какое такое? Мы говорим о конкретном действии, не более. И в ответах просто примеры, как выполнить это разными способами.

Answer (score 1):

> Хочу обе переменные внести в файл

Используя подпроцессы, в вопросе не удивил как именно вы в файл отсылаете переменные

*echo_subprocess.sh*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

URL="https://git.git.ru/scm/hg/common/cpp"
SHORT="fc88eab89100"
TEST_1="random minds"
TEST_2="cluttered! // thinking \\ "


{
    echo "$URL"
    echo "$SHORT"
    echo "$TEST_1"
    echo "$TEST_2"
} | tee free_hugs
# tee  тут для наглядности, используйте > если единожды пишите в файл
# или >> если нужно до этого файл уже был создан.
# end of script
```

Проверка

```
~$ chmod +x ./echo_subprocess.sh
~$ ./echo_subprocess.sh
https://git.git.ru/scm/hg/common/cpp
fc88eab89100
random minds
cluttered! // thinking \

~$ cat free_hugs
https://git.git.ru/scm/hg/common/cpp
fc88eab89100
random minds
cluttered! // thinking \
```

Если имелось в виду то, что в заголовке вопроса:

> bash, echo несколько строк объединить в одну

То нужно добавить ключ

> -n        do not append a newline

```
~$ ./echo_subprocess.sh
https://git.git.ru/scm/hg/common/cppfc88eab89100random mindscluttered! // thinking \ 

~$ cat free_hugs
https://git.git.ru/scm/hg/common/cppfc88eab89100random mindscluttered! // thinking \
```

Дополнение

Может автору нужно "склеить" список в одну строчку

```
~$ find / -maxdepth 1 -type d | paste -ds" " -
/
/var
/dev
/etc
/mnt
/home
/root
/opt
/run
/lost+found
/srv
/boot
/proc
/media
/sys
/usr
/library
/tmp

~$ find / -maxdepth 1 -type d | paste -sd" " -
/ /var /dev /etc /mnt /home /root /opt /run /lost+found /srv /boot /proc /media /sys /usr /library /tmp
```